# Use JMeter Webdriver (Plugin Selenium) to make HTTP Header Manager and see results in Dynatrace

Tags: selenium, jmeter, http-headers, dynatrace

I'd like to know how can I put the HTTP header manager in `JMeter` if I use `Selenium Webdriver Sampler`.

I know that there is the standard tool(HTTP Header Manager) in JMeter but that tool is useful when I use HTTP Request in my test. In this case for testing, I use only WebDriver Sampler with Java 1.8. The goal is to see in dynatrace the tags that I send from JMeter. Is it possible to do that? And if it is the answer is positive, how can I do that? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

1. WebDriver Sampler doesn't respect HTTP Header Manager
2. [WebDriver itself doesn't support working with HTTP Headers](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/141) and the feature is unlikely to be implemented ever

So the options are in:

1. Use an extension like [ModHeader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en), but in this case you will have so switch from the WebDriver Sampler to [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler). Example code:

   ```
   def options = new org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions()
   options.addExtensions(new File('/path/to/modheaders.crx'))
   def capabilities = new org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities()
   capabilities.setCapability(org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options)
   def driver = new org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver(capabilities)


   driver.get('http://example.com')
   ```
2. Use a proxy like [BrowserMob](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy) as the proxy for the WebDriver and configure it to add headers to each intercepted request. Example initialization code (you can put it into the aformentioned JSR223 Sampler somewhere in [setUp Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler))

   ```
   def proxy = new net.lightbody.bmp.BrowserMobProxyServer()
   def proxyPort = 8080
   proxy.setTrustAllServers(true)
   proxy.addRequestFilter((request, contents, info) -> {
       request.headers().add('your header name', 'your header value')
       return null
   })
   proxy.start(proxyPort)
   ```